# How to Implement connection pooling in Birt reports

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

I am using birt tool for generating reports.Birt is deployed in tomcat server.I want to know how to implement connection pooling in birt reports.Is it possible through connection string.I have referred lot of articles,but not get a proper answer.Can anyone pls help on ths??

Answer (score 1):

We can definitely do this: we need to setup a connection pool in context.xml of the Tomcat server, and declare it in WEB-INF/web.xml of web applications which make use of this pool (BIRT webviewer in your case). See [Apache JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](http://www.visioneo.org/knowledge-base/-/knowledge_base/article/122720) for detailed informations.

For example, here is "web.xml" given as example in Apache documentation:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <description>MySQL Test App</description>
  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

With this configuration file, jdbc BIRT datasources can be plugged to the pool in Eclipse using a connection string like this(through JNDI URL property):

```
java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB
```

BIRT will always try to connect to a JNDI URL of a datasource first, if it does not work it makes use of a direct JDBC access as a fallback. Follow [this link](http://www.visioneo.org/knowledge-base/-/knowledge_base/article/122720) for more details